# Winlogon entry userinit Data

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

What is the difference between the two data strings

C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe,

and

C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe

in the context of the windows registry at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

REG_SZ Userinit

what does the comma signify or the lack of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing comma is necessary. It ensures that any settings added by another piece of software or GPO are **delimited as necessary**. Most errors related to this occur because the installation routines are not configured to place the comma at the end of the string; the key is corrupted because it is not read properly unless it is delimited correctly.

[source](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1028975)

So comma acts as a delimiter.If delimiter is not present key will not be read properly.

So comma will be always used to separate values in all files.

To understand better please see this [tutorial](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-edit-windows-registry-key-values-without-booting-in-windows/).

Comment: swapyonubuntu: Ok, similar to the ; used in environment variables paths.

Comment: yes correct its similar...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure in this specific instance, but a comma usually means a backup file in my experience.